# Using SED to remove newlines for an address range

Tags: regex, sed

I am having some difficulty getting my SED script to work properly.  It appears to only work on the first occurrence.  I am basically a UNIX beginner - please bear with me.

Data file looks like this:

```
exec cics 
end-exec.
exec cics 
send map
end-exec.
exec cics 
end-exec.
```

Actual output is as follows and appears to work correctly only on the first occurrence:

```
exec cics end-exec.
exec cics 
send map
end-exec.
exec cics 
end-exec.
```

Desired output should be as follows:

```
exec cics end-exec.
exec cics send map end-exec.
exec cics end-exec.
```

Everything starting with "exec cics" and ending with "end-exec" should be on one line with any newlines removed.

SED script is as follows:

```
/exec cics/,/end-exec/{
:a    
N
$!ba
s/\n//
}
```

I had got the code within the curly braces from here: [How can I replace a newline (\n) using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n)

My initial script did not have the `:a;N;$!ba`.  Can anyone see what I am missing or doing wrong?

Comment: You should note that the x-ref'd question uses `s/\n/ /g` rather than `s/\n//`.

Answer (score 2):

The result that you get can be explained by the fact that you substitute only the first newline:

```
s/\n//
```

However, even if you performed the substitution globally, i.e. used:

```
s/\n//g
```

you'd get:

```
exec cics end-exec. exec cics  send map end-exec. exec cics  end-exec.
```

because the `$` address would match the last occurrence in the file.

Instead of branching to the label `a` unless you match the last line, don't branch when you encounter `end-exec`.  Saying:

```
sed '/exec cics/,/end-exec/{:a;N;/end-exec/!ba;s/\n/ /g}' filename
```

would produce:

```
exec cics end-exec.
exec cics send map end-exec.
exec cics end-exec.
```

---

If your input consists of contiguous blocks starting from `exec cisc` and ending with `end-exec`, you could simplify it:

```
sed ':a;N;/end-exec/!ba;s/\n/ /g' filename
```

Comment: The second solution seems to be the most efficient.

Answer (score 1):

If you like to try `awk`

```
awk '{printf (/exec cics/ && NR>1?RS:"")"%s",$0} END {print ""}'
exec cics end-exec.
exec cics send mapend-exec.
exec cics end-exec.
```

If line starts with `exec cics` and not is first line, add newline before the line.
Else, just print the data in one line.

Answer (score 1):

This modified version of your `sed` script seems to do the job:

```
/exec cics/,/end-exec/{
    :a
    /end-exec/! N
    s/\n/ /g
    t a
}
```

When saved in the file `sed.script`, and given the data file (`data2`):

```
exec cics
end-exec.
exec cics
send map
end-exec.
exec cics
end-exec.
exec cics
do this
and that
and tother
end-exec.
```

(with no trailing blanks on any of the data lines), then I get:

```
$ sed -f sed.script data2
exec cics end-exec.
exec cics send map end-exec.
exec cics end-exec.
exec cics do this and that and tother end-exec.
$
```

What does the script do?

1. For each range of lines between `exec cics` and `end-exec`,
2. Set label `a`,
3. If the pattern space doesn't contain `end-exec` add another line to it.
4. Replace any newlines with spaces.
5. If there was a substitution, jump back to label `a`.

While debugging/devising this, I added a couple of extra lines after the `t` and before the `}`:

```
s/^/[[/
s/$/]]/
```

This helped me see how the data was handled with various other versions of the commands, including the original; the lines were enclosed in `[[` and `]]` as they were printed.

Tested on Mac OS X 10.9.2 Mavericks using the BSD `sed` that's supplied.

Comment: +1 for the explanation (and for making it work with BSD `:)`). The `g` flag in the solution is redundant though, since we are running the substitution every time after appending the next line.

Comment: @jaypal: yes, the global suffix on the substitute is not needed, though it is unlikely to do measurable harm being present.  One version of the script needed it, I think, but it was long enough ago now that I don't remember for sure.

Comment: Certainly, no harm done by it being present. I was just thinking along the lines that instead of doing the substitution on every line that is appended, a better and less expensive approach would be to build our entire line first and then do a global substitution just once. The second solution proposed by [devnull](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23595491/970195) seems to do that, though it is GNU `sed` only.